How can I identify what causes an Intermittent CloudFront 500 error?
On my page https://squareballoon.co.uk/blog I'm using CloudFront to load images from Amazon S3.
If I just use Amazon S3 directly the images all have an expiry date of an hour.
If I use CloudFront it seems to not have that issue.  BUT... I think about 50% of the time the assets don't load.  Some of the assets on that page are loaded locally and they always work fine.  The ones that don't load are a 500 error.

The problem is very intermittent.  But it seems pretty consistent (if you can say that), for example if I load the page 10 times at least 3-4 of them usually the assets don't load.

Could this be because I am loading the images too quickly over and over and there's a setting  against this?  Obviously, that's an issue for a website as it could be loaded by many users.
I have spent hours trying to solve this issue, I don't really know how to describe it well and I find AWS docs quite difficult.
What could cause it to work sometimes but not all times.  I'm struggling to see a variable to troubleshoot, nothing changes when it doesn't work.
To make things harder... the AWS console doesn't usually load for me so I can't login to make changes easily.  I have contacted my ISP to understand this but they say it's not them.

Can you share the image response. Is it the 500 with Error in cloudfront ?

At the moment, I don't see the assets served with Cloudfront. Can you elaborate on your configuration in Cloudfront? Also for the login issue, try to disable any ad blockers or extensions if you have any in the browser. https://repost.aws/questions/QUPf619UtRRv20ScpNhpeO1A/not-able-to-access-vpc-management-console-getting-network-failure-errors

Thanks @ManojAcharya I have tried in multiple browsers in incognito mode.  Nothing works.  Except using a VPN.  Which is why I thought this must be my ISP.  Using a VPN was fine but then I would get blocked by Google and others for suspicious activity because it was a free one.

@ManojAcharya I have updated my question with a screenshot.  Not all images are loaded by CloudFront.  Ideally they all would be but with this issue recurring I am not confident of doing that yet.

@Eoin Why is the url has both the domain name and cloudfront distribution id in the url ?. Is the url correct?

https://ddixi6n6oidt6.cloudfront.net/blogs/excel-dropdowns/how-to-add-dropdowns-in-excel--intro.png#joomlaImage://s3-S3/blogs/excel-dropdowns/how-to-add-dropdowns-in-excel--intro.png?width=446&height=446 I see this.  I only see the CloudFront Distribution.  My next step if it works would be to use a subdomain so I mask the CloudFront part.  But if you are asking about the part after the # it's because of a plugin I'm using with Joomla.  I'm 100% certain that works the developer is strong and an expert in Joomla.  Plus I know others using the plugin.
